# Manual git pull is able to copy latest master repository code but when I pull from Jenkins build job old master is getting pulled

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Manual git pull is able to copy latest master repository code but when I pull from Jenkins build job old master is getting pulled.
we can see old pull request in below logs but not the latest.

Please help me on this.
Thanks

```
01:48:26  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
01:48:26  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
01:48:27 Checking out Revision b971a3367b2e015d83a34d0ba2cb92a3bf1e916a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
01:48:27 Enabling Git LFS pull
01:48:27  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
01:48:27  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f b971a3367b2e015d83a34d0ba2cb92a3bf1e916a # timeout=10
01:48:31  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
01:48:31 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Manny Bitbucket Key
01:48:31  > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe lfs pull origin # timeout=10
01:49:06 Commit message: "Merged in LicenseTestsScenario (pull request #41)"
```

Comment: Are doing a replay of an old build in Jenkins ? If it is the case you should build the job to take your latest modifications in Bitbucket.

Comment: Please make an effort to at least format the log. That aside, the issue could potentially be that you or somebody else has pushed a branch that matches the wildcard "*/master" but is not your actual latest master branch.